# Xampp start giving errors

Tags: ubuntu, xampp, ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-10.10

I am installing XAMPP on ubuntu10.10

(i) i have extracted `tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.7.7.tar.gz -C ./opt` into the opt folder

(ii) When i write: `sudo ./opt/lampp/lampp start`
I am getting the following errors:

```
cat: /opt/lampp/lib/VERSION: No such file or directory
./lampp: line 126: /opt/lampp/share/lampp/selinux: No such file or directory
Starting XAMPP for Linux ...
./lampp: line 133: /opt/lampp/share/lampp/nogroupcheck: No such file or directory
cat: /opt/lampp/lib/VERSION: No such file or directory 
./lampp: line 126: /opt/lampp/share/lampp/selinux: No such file or directory
XAMPP: Another web server daemon is already running.
cat: /opt/lampp/lib/VERSION: No such file or directory
./lampp: line 126: /opt/lampp/share/lampp/selinux: No such file or directory
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...
./lampp: line 253: /opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: No such file or directory
XAMPP: Couldn't start MySQL!
cat: /opt/lampp/lib/VERSION: No such file or directory
./lampp: line 126: /opt/lampp/share/lampp/selinux: No such file or directory
./lampp: line 140: /opt/lampp/share/lampp/alladdons: No such file or directory
XAMPP for Linux started.
```

I searched through several forms on the net, but i am unable to rectify the error. I am a novice as far as xampp is concerned, so please excuse my ignore and help me find a solution?

Comment: Why is this question getting 3 upvotes?

Comment: May be other users are also facing the similar problem..or getting stuck in a similar manner..i m trying to solve my problem myself..if i am done i post it..else if somebody else knows then please help

Comment: it's not `./opt` but `/opt` - which is found on your root drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have not extracted "tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.7.7.tar.gz -C ./opt into the opt folder" with root privileges.i.e.

```
sudo tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.7.7.tar.gz -C /opt into the opt folder 
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Try and do so with root privileges..I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

`./opt` will use a directory relative to your current working directory. XAMPP uses a hard-coded value of `/opt/lampp/` as it's directory. Make sure you're actually extracting to /opt, not ./opt

```
sudo tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.7.7.tar.gz -C /opt
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Answer (score -1):

This is happen when you don't give the correct path for the script.